# reading csv file. different variables not detected

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have read loads of csv files into r. For some reason this file I am working on, with several variables is read as if it had only 1 variable.
R loads it and adds it to the global environment, the number of rows is right, but there is only 1 column.

It never happened before. Have been looking around for a solution but can't find one. thanks!

I have tried the following code:

```
read.csv("file.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
read.csv("file.csv")
read.table("file.csv",sep=",")
```

[image of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9GLF.png)

Comment: Maybe the separator is not a comma. Regardless, we can only guess. Please try to post a simple, reproducible example

Comment: If you are using rstudio then you can try using 'Import Dataset' from enviornment tab and see which separator works best for your dataset.You can have view also.

Comment: There is nothing we can help unless the example is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found out what the problem was. I had checked if the commas were actually commas and I copied and pasted them and they looked like commas and behaved like commas but to make sure I decided to replace (within excel) all commas by semicolons. Then I read the file again and it worked. thanks for the replies!